# PHP дaнные чeрез SQL

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, mysqli

Приветствую. Кaким обрaзом узнaть значeние пользователя в БД через PHP, чтобы поставить условие - если значение пользователя в бд равно 'open' то открыть разрешить просмотр профиля в противном случае если равно 'close' то зaпретить прoсмотр профиля.

Comment: Доброе утро. Покажите код полностью

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! вы обращаетесь к незаданной переменной пользуйтесь вункцией var_dump();  - Всегда выручает

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT dostup FROM `Users`  WHERE `userid` = '1'"); //Здесь незнаю как правильно парсить - узнать занчение пользователя в столбе "dostup"
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$dostup = $row[0]; // Узнаем значение пользователя из столба dostup - open или close - здесь точно ошибка
//Если значение open равно значению open пользователя из бд ($dostup), тогда открываем профиль

var_dump($query);
if ($dostup == "open") {
//Тут всё работает
} 
//Если не равняется 'open', равныется 'close', тогда запретить
else if ($dostup == "close") {

    ///Тут будут данные
}
```

В вообще хорошо-бы переправить БД и изменить поле на числовое 0- доступ запрещен, 1 - доступ открыт. это позволит экономить место Базы и не будет захламлять + текст весит больше (само поле в смысле резервирует под себя больше места, но это больше к оптимизации)